# How to count the voltage pulses of a digital temperature sensor using Arduino Mega Atmega2560?

Tags: arduino-mega

I have a digital temperature sensor which gives digital output in the form of current pulses. The number of pulses corresponds to a particular temperature.

I have converted the current pulses to voltage pulses using transistor as a level shifter. I want to count the number of pulses for a time interval of 50ms each time.

Please help me with the algo and the code.

Comment: Please give us more information such as which temperature sensor you are using, your circuit diagram, what you have tried and perhaps your code so far. See [ask].

Comment: I'm using lmt01 digital sensor . I'm a beginner in coding . So counting the no. Of current pulses is also fine .

Answer (score 3):

There are function called [pulseIn](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) which probably need exactly what you want.

Just set a variable with the current 'time' ([millis](http://%20millis()), start counting until the current time reaches 50 ms later.

So something like (not checked):

```
unsigned long timer = millis();
unsigned pulses = 0;
while (timer + 50 < millis())
{
  pulseIn(PIN, LOW);
  pulses++;
}
```

PIN is a constant or variable that defines the pin number to check, LOW is to check low pulses, you also can use high, and optionally you can add a timeout. For example, you can use the timeout to check the last timeout is within the 50 ms region. Or to be more precise, check if the pulse was within the same 50 ms:

```
unsigned long timer = millis();
unsigned pulses = 0;
while (timer + 50 < millis())
{
  pulseIn(PIN, LOW);
  if (timer + 50 < millis())
  {
    pulses++;
  }
}
```